# TableSorter 2.0 Plugin - Enable Table scroll

Tags: jquery, css, tablesorter

I am using the Tablesorter plugin and it works great. Currently, I achieve table scrolling using a div wrapper. Is it possible to make the table scroll, keeping the headers visible while scrolling and not using any divs?

Comment: ... And a 2013-CrossBrowser solution??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this CSS, adjusting the height to suit:

```
tbody{height: 4em; overflow: scroll}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/ofice

Answer (score 2):

As showed above (or [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/krauss/KWFPq/)), to be cross-browser (and any doctype) the `tbody` and `thead` tags need CSS *display* as block. If you need to show scrollbar OUTSIDE of `tbody`, or need to use not-standard browsers, you need more complex solution:

## For display scrollbar outside or use with old browsers

The solution is to split the table's `thead` and `tbody` in two distinct tables, then, use a `div` to control the scroll (overflow-y) of the second (tbody content) table.

Trade-offs:

- need to split into two tables (jQuery can do by creatig second table and coping thead);
- need to align both by add widthes.

Related questions:

- [Is there a direct purpose for HTML's tbody?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/923655/287948)
- [<table> : How can <thead> be displayed while scrolling through <tbody> in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12920304/287948)
- [Strict DocType imposes minimum table row height in FF/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3931835/287948)

---

### Examples

- splitted table (by hand): http://jsfiddle.net/krauss/B9NsU/1/
- *jQuery* copying `thread` in a separate table:  http://jsfiddle.net/krauss/yLGg6/1/

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am answering this old post to update on the progress of TableSorter jQuery plugin.

You can use a fork of this plugin by @Mottie (http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html)

Then just on DOM ready, run this script:

```
 $('table').tablesorter({
        widgets        : ['zebra', 'columns', 'stickyHeaders']
    });
```

All you have to include for this to work:

1) jquery.tablesorter.js

2) jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js

3) any of the css themes, eg: theme.blue.css

StickyHeaders widget will do the trick for you.