# Strict DocType imposes minimum table row height in FF/Chrome

Tags: html, css

Something i'd never noticed before, but it seems that in Chrome/Firefox (and probably Opera/Safari, i've not checked those specifically) using a strict doctype prevents table rows from being displayed smaller than a value that i'm unable to determine the calculation of.

The following document displays as one might imagine in IE7 with all table rows around 8px in height to match the height of the content (which is probably incorrect knowing IE), whilst in Chome/Firefox the rows are all 23px tall. No combination of border-collapse, padding, margin etc i've found will allow the rows to be smaller than this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD Xhtml 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    span {
      font-family: Verdana;
      font-size: 8px;
      line-height: 8px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table cellspacing="1" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td><span>One</span></td>
      <td><span>Two</span></td>
      <td><span>Three</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Four</span></td>
      <td><span>Five</span></td>
      <td><span>Six</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span>Seven</span></td>
      <td><span>Eight</span></td>
      <td><span>Nine</span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>  
</body>
</html>
```

Setting the doctype to transitional causes the table rows to display around 8px in height as expected.

Does anyone have any idea what's causing this apparent minimum row height?

Cheers for any info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the line-height on the `<td>` aswell as the `<span>`

```
td{line-height:8px;}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's got it. Any idea why the default seems to be about 23px? Seems a weird thing to impose, in strict mode only

Comment: You hadn't set a font size or line height for the document, just the span tag, so the default was being used. If for example you set the body to font-size:8px all child elemnts would take on this value, including your td tag.

Comment: Thanks alot. I had spent hours investigating this issue, before getting here!

Answer (score 1):

Heres a better explination:

View the code below in your browser.

Notice that even though we've set the font-size of the second set of `<span>` tags the actual table cells are the same size.

This is because the font size of the table cells **IS** still the same. We've only changed a child element of them, ie the `<span>`

setting `body{font-size:8px}` would work fine as the table will inherit this value.
You can also use it directly on the table ie `table{font-size:8px}`, or you can use it on the cell as posted above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD Xhtml 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    body{}
    td{}
    span {font-family: Verdana;}

    span.small{font-size:8px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Default font size</h1>
  <table cellspacing="1" border="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span>One</span></td>
          <td><span>Two</span></td>
          <td><span>Three</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span>Four</span></td>
          <td><span>Five</span></td>
          <td><span>Six</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span>Seven</span></td>
          <td><span>Eight</span></td>
          <td><span>Nine</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>  

  <h2>8px font size</h2>
   <table cellspacing="1" border="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="small">One</span></td>
          <td><span class="small">Two</span></td>
          <td><span class="small">Three</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="small">Four</span></td>
          <td><span class="small">Five</span></td>
          <td><span class="small">Six</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="small">Seven</span></td>
          <td><span class="small">Eight</span></td>
          <td><span class="small">Nine</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That's great, thanks for helping to clear it up. Just marginally confused as to why strict mode imposes a default font size on all elements, whereas transitional seems to have none