# How to set border to <tbody> element?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Why doesn't the border show around `tbody` in the following? I tried `rules="groups"` and the border appears, but only between the two `tbody` sections and it is collapsed.

```css
table.sectioned tbody {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 4px;
}
```

```html
<table class="sectioned">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><b>General Data</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Tail Number</td><td>N0809021</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Type of Ownership</td><td>personal</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Type of Aircraft</td><td>aircraft under 13,000 pounds</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Year of Manufacture</td><td>1999</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Use of Aircraft</td><td>private</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Start Date</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Policy Length</td><td>6 months</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><b>Additional Aircraft Information</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Manufacturer</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Model</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Engine Make</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Number of Seats</td><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Add display:block and the border will show up.

Comment: @Keith, tbody is a container element for the body part of a table element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923655/is-there-a-direct-purpose-for-htmls-tbody

Comment: Thanks, Barbara. display:block did get the border to show up, although without border-spacing.  Is there any way to get border-spacing to work here?

Comment: Altering the display type of the tbody has caused an anonymous table element to be inserted *within* the tbody.  You can't style anonymous HTML elements.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Add:

```
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/PwYtR/)

Answer (score 10):

Add display:block to your tbody style. Try this

```
tbody{
    display:block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 4px; 
}
```

You can test it out on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPL86/)

Comment: Thanks, Brian. That did the trick. And the margin-bottom: 10px in your fiddle caused the borders to separate.

Comment: Note that modifying the display type of the tbody makes the columns not line up anymore:  http://jsfiddle.net/bPL86/1/

Comment: I see that, cimmanon. It's as if each tbody becomes its own table.  Too bad. I guess the best I can do with that is make the first column a fixed width.

Comment: ...I still think table was the solution no need for display:block but whatever serves your boat

Comment: @user1981459 that margin was for aesthetic purposes :) and you're welcome

Answer (score 6):

Use `box-shadow` instead of `border`. It works no matter which value of `border-collapse` was applied. In addition, you can also apply `border-radius` to it.

```css
tbody {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your answer if I have seen it on time, would have saved me at least 4 hours of effort trying to set a border to a <tbody> element. Now it saved me probably a few days of Googling that were coming ahead. And yet, I still wonder, why is it not possible to set a border to a regular HTML element like <tbody>? I saw on https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tbody.asp that it's meant to be used only in particular context, e.g. with rowgroup, but this does not answer my question why is it so. Does anybody have an idea why was this designed this way at all in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

```
.table_body, .tbody_td, .tbody_th 
{ border: 1px solid black; }
.table_body  { border-collapse: collapse; }
<table>
<thead> 
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="table_body">
<tr>
<td class="tbody_td">Jill</td>
<td class="tbody_td">Smith</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tbody_td">Eve</td>
<td class="tbody_td">Jackson</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```