# Cannot set width fixed table header

Tags: html, css

I want to have a fixed table header. If the table is scrolled the table header stays on top.
Unfortunately it loses its width information. how can i improve the table?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MH943/1/)

### HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>From</td>
            <td>Subject</td>
            <td>Date</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Peter Pan</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>30.06.2014</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Lisa Lama</td>
            <td>Banana</td>
            <td>10.03.2013</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Steven</td>
            <td>Tuba</td>
            <td>12.01.2013</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### CSS

```
.wrap{
    border: 4px solid lightgrey;
    height: 100px;
    width: 470px;
    overflow: auto;
}

table{
    width: 400px;
}

table tr:first-child{
    background: lightgrey;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: fixed;

}

td{   
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Not a right way for doing fixed header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table with fixed header and column on pure css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811653/table-with-fixed-header-and-column-on-pure-css)

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/2TyLg/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the header elements of your table in a `<thead>` tag and the scrollable part in `<tbody>`. Then set the height of `<tbody>` and give it `overflow-y: scroll`

More info in this question: [Is there a direct purpose for HTML's tbody?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923655/is-there-a-direct-purpose-for-htmls-tbody)