# CSS How to highlight two rows in a table as one on hover?

Tags: html, css

My problem is, I want to highlight the table row below of the row which I'm hovering currently.

However, the problem I'm facing is that after two rows it should then highlight the next two rows. Basically that every two rows of the table highlight as one.

So if rows 2 and 3 are being highlighted, when I hover over row 4 only 4 and 5 are being highlighted, 6 and 7 and so on.

Currently, on hover, it just highlights the row the mouse is on.
Is something like this possible using CSS? Or have I just overlooked something obvious.

```
table tr:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
#table tr:nth-child(4n+5) {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
#table tr:hover {
  background: #3498DB;
}
```

See my work here: http://jsfiddle.net/g5o7v6qe/21/

Sorry, if my question is a bit confusing or worded in a difficult manner, I do have some understanding of HTML and CSS but this for some reason stumped me. Thank you.

Comment: tr:hover, tr:hover + tr {
  background: #3498DB;
} + What about the first and last?

Comment: what happens if you hover row 3? does it highlight row 2 or doesnt do anything ?

Comment: Using @VXp suggestion it works but oddly, so if row 2 is hovered on then both row 2 and 3 will highlight. If row 3 is hovered on then only row 3 is highlighted and the rows 4n+4 and 4n+5 are ignored completely from the hover.

Comment: You need to delete those and leave only the line I wrote. Remove: #table tr:nth-child(4n+4) {...} and #table tr:nth-child(4n+5) {...}

Comment: @VXp he's using adjacent sibling selector, it only selects an element behind of it, if you want something like hover row 3 and row 2 is highlighted i dont think it will work. there's no selecting previous element yet in css.

Comment: Okay I now understand what going on, but it's not quite what I want. So now it highlights 2 rows based on hover over row 1 - highlight row 1 and 2, hover over row 2 - highlight row 2 and 3. But is it possible to do something like hover over row 1 or 2 - highlight row 1 and 2 then hover over row 3 or 4 - highlight row 3 and 4 and so on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution you're searching for is sadly not possible with CSS alone, because CSS doesn't offer selectors for selecting preceding children (which you would need to also highlight the row above when hovering over the description). Instead, you could modify your HTML a bit to make this possible:

> Introducing the `tbody` element !

The `tbody` element can used in conjunction with `thead` and `tfoot` to e.g. enable scrolling while locking the header and footer of the table in place. Also, when printing, the header and footer may get repeated on the next page, should the table span multiple pages. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923655/what-is-the-purpose-for-htmls-tbody) for more details.

What a lot of people don't know, is that you can have multiple `tbody` elements within a single table. That means you can wrap each group of rows in your table in a `tbody` element and then style each one appropriately:

```css
#table {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: auto;
}

#table td,
#table th {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  padding: 8px;
}

#table th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
}

#table tbody:nth-child(2n+3) {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
}

/* Group highlights */
#table tbody:hover {
  background: #3498D8;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Vendor</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Source</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>vendor1</td>
      <td>model1</td>
      <td>year1</td>
      <td>source1</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">description1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>vendor2</td>
      <td>model2</td>
      <td>year2</td>
      <td>source2</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">description2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>vendor3</td>
      <td>model3</td>
      <td>year3</td>
      <td>source3</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">description3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>vendor4</td>
      <td>model4</td>
      <td>year4</td>
      <td>source4</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">description4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

P.s.: While you're at it, you might also want to nest your table header in a `thead` element for the sake of consistency.

Comment: Thank you that works perfectly, 100% and is what I was trying to achieve. I have accepted your answer, and thank you to everyone else who has contributed.

Comment: Any down sides of adding lots of tbody in your table?

Comment: @Persijn not that I know of. Only thing I can think of is that they should all be in consecutive order. Utilizing multiple tbody tags is also described on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody#Multiple_bodies

Answer (score 2):

So in my understanding you want it like that: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5o7v6qe/56/)

```
#table tr:nth-child(2n+2):hover {
  background: #3498DB;
}

#table tr:nth-child(2n+2):hover + tr {
  background: #3498DB;
}
```

Starting at the second row with `nth-child(2n+2)` it highlights every 2 rows on hover.

With `+ tr` you achieve that all `tr` that are an adjacent sibling of an hovered `tr` get highlighted.

Hope that makes sense to you.

EDIT: Notice that this works not for hovering the 2nd row of each row group to highlight the group. So this is not a - full - solution to the Problem.

Comment: the only thing that's missing is when you hover over the second row of a pair it won't highlight the group.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript table highlight

Css does not let you selected a sibling upwards in the dom.

Here is how i would solve it in JS:

```js
$(function() {
  //Selected all rows with a data-group attribute
  let rows = $("tr[data-group]");
  //on hover over 
  rows.hover(function over() {
    let group = $(this).data("group");
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
    $(this).siblings("tr[data-group=" + group + "]").addClass("highlight");
    //on hover out
  }, function out() {
    let group = $(this).data("group");
    $(this).removeClass("highlight");
    $(this).siblings("tr[data-group=" + group + "]").removeClass("highlight");
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-group="1">
    <td>element1</td>
    <td>element2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="1">
    <td colspan="2">Long element</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="2">
    <td>element1</td>
    <td>element2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="2">
    <td colspan="2">Long element</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="3">
    <td>element1</td>
    <td>element2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="3">
    <td colspan="2">Long element</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="4">
    <td>element1</td>
    <td>element2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-group="4">
    <td colspan="2">Long element</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you would like to achieve?

***Also I've revised the incorrect html markup and css.***

```css
#table {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: auto;
}

#table td,
#table th {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  padding: 8px;
}

#table tr:nth-child(4n+3) {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
}

#table tr:nth-child(4n+4) {
  background-color: #EBEBEB;
}

#table tr:hover td,
#table tr:nth-child(2n+1):hover td,
#table tr:nth-child(2n+1):hover + tr td {
  background: #3498DB;
}

#table th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Vendor</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Source</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>vendor1</td>
      <td>model1</td>
      <td>year1</td>
      <td>source1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">description1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>vendor2</td>
      <td>model2</td>
      <td>year2</td>
      <td>source2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">description2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>vendor3</td>
      <td>model3</td>
      <td>year3</td>
      <td>source3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">description3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>vendor4</td>
      <td>model4</td>
      <td>year4</td>
      <td>source4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">description4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh thank you @Chaska that is great! That is what I was wanting. Is it maybe possible that when the description is highlight it also highlights the above row? If not no worries.

Comment: Don't think it's possible to be done with pre css. Btw I've revised the code and there's no need to add extra class name.

Comment: @MacGenius You can't, you can do one thing, but it fails with the other. You can highlight the desc. and it will highlight the associated one, but when vice versa it will just highlight the one after it in the DOM. I'm talking about flexbox/grid and the order property. http://jsfiddle.net/g5o7v6qe/80/ Not possible atm., i.e. can't go up, yet...

Comment: No worries I understand now why it won't work the way I would like it to, but still thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for highlighting the next two row in a table when we hover on a particular row.

```css
td, th {
  padding: 10px;
}
tr.head-row {
  background: grey;
}
tr:not(.head-row) {
  background: #fff5f5;
}


/* highlight the current row on hover*/
tr:hover:not(.head-row) {
    background: #f8b5b5;
}

/* highlight next row on hovering a row */
tr:hover:not(.head-row) + tr {
    background: #91cefe;
}

/* highlight next to next row on hovering a row */
tr:hover:not(.head-row) + tr + tr {
    background: #67ace1;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="table">
  <tr class="head-row">
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eveas</td>
    <td>Jackson we</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Everrr</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve ff</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eveas</td>
    <td>Jackson we</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Everrr</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve ff</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```